# Gulp Task - Compilar Stylus para CSS

Tags: css, front-end, gulp, stylus

Depois de muita luta, comecei a fazer a página do meu portfolio. Aproveitei pra usar umas coisinhas que estava aprendendo, dentre elas o Gulp e Stylus. Para a construção do CSS estou usando a metodologia(entendo como arquitetura) ITCSS. Porém, na hora de executar a task do Gulp estou recebendo uns erros.

Eu já atualizei a versão do Gulp e do Node.

Minha task no gulp

```
//Importa os módulos necessários para o Gulp, inclusive ele mesmo
var gulp = require( 'gulp' );
var concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css');
var stylus = require('gulp-stylus');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');

//Tarefa para compilar, concatenar e comprimir o css
gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/styl/*.styl')
        .pipe(stylus())
        .pipe(concatCss("style.css"))
        .pipe(minifyCss({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css/'));
});
```

No meu `base.styl` eu tenho o código abaixo:

```
body
  background-color: red
```

No meu `settings.styl`:

```
/*====================
 *=====Variáveis
 *====================/

//Cores
$color-white: #fff

//Media Queries
media_queries = {
  thin-mobile: "only screen and (min-width: 320px)",
  medium-mobile: "only screen and (min-width: 480px)",
  large-mobile: "only screen and (min-width: 600px)",
  tablet: "only screen and (min-width: 768px)",
  deskto: "only screen and (min-width: 900px)"
}
```

Ele não está parseando o meu código do Stylus. Ao executar a task eu recebo:

> Potentially unhandled rejection[2] Error: No writecb in Transform
>   Class

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu só tiver o arquivo `base.styl` ele parseia normalmente. Mas ai com o `settings.styl` no meio já dá o erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resolução foi super simples. Esqueci de ater-me a um detalhe: como são declaradas as variáveis no **Stylus**.

#### Como eu fiz

```
$myVar : #fff
```

#### Como se faz

```
$myVar = #fff
```

ou

```
myVar = #fff
```